# How to give a database as an input for a Perl script?

Tags: database, perl

I have written a Perl script which reads a whole directory and takes all the files in a directory as input. Now, instead of giving a directory as a input, I want to give a database as a input and it must read all the tables in the database like reading the files in a directory.

How can I do this?  Please suggest me a way or an idea.

Comment: There are cpan modules for working with many database formats. And most dbs also have a command for listing all tables (compared to `ls`, for directories).

Comment: could you please attach some references .. and will listing the tables in a database will be considered same as files in a directory?

Comment: `DBD::MySql` is one such module. there are numerous tutorials for it online, including http://www.t-scripts.com/perl/

Comment: `show tables;` shows a list of tables in `sqlite`; there's a similar command for mysql or mssql, which are 3 I'm familiar with; it returns a list of the table names. It would prob. return as an array of table rows, just like any other db access.

Comment: Sounds like a schoolbook example of OOP polymorphism. Define two accessor classes, one for a database, the other for a directory, and refactor your code to talk to the back ends through this interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Perl [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) (DataBase Interface) is the primary DBMS-neutral interface to databases.  There are separate [DBD](http://search.cpan.org/modlist/Database_Interfaces/DBD) (DataBase Driver) modules for the different DBMS.  You need both DBI and the appropriate DBD module to access a database.  You can find all this on CPAN, of course, under [Database Interfaces](http://search.cpan.org/modlist/Database_Interfaces).

Within DBI, there are methods for interrogating the system catalog, to find the names of tables and the columns in a table and the types and so on and so forth.  You could use that to conduct your scouting mission.